# tortoisesvn: create branches in separate directories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How do I create a branch in a separate directories with tortoisesvn?  When I tried to create a branch, it was created in the same directory.  I created this by right clicked on the dir with my code and navigated to 'branch/tag'.   Since I have files in the branch that isn't under revision control, I want them to be in different directories.

Comment: Hey Brian can you bit more clear,do you already have a directory 'tag' under branch and now you want to add your files under a new directory say 'tag1'

Comment: Currently I have a dir called <c:/myProgram> that is under revision control.  I don't have any tags/branches.  I'd like to create a branch in a folder called <c:/derivative>.

Comment: see you are using the term branch interchangeably. Branch is something which you have in SVN. Directory is which you have on your HardDrive. so now as i understand you want to map the same branch from SVN to two diffrent directories on your HardDrive.

Comment: I have a svn repo at: <c:/repo>
I have my code checked out at: <c:/myProgram> 
I want to create a branch and check it out to: <c:/derivative>

Comment: this is what you cant do. You should always have one to one relationship between a branch in SVN and directory on Harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow trunk/branch/tag layout, you should have working copy retrieved from **svn_url/project/trunk** in **c:/myProgram** and see no branches there. If you see them then you either checked out the whole **svn_url/project** without reason, or trying to create branch in trunk - which is wrong.

The same way that you have checked out repository to **c:/myProgram** you can checkout any branch from your repository (or tag) to any other location at the same time, e.g. **c:/derivative**. See [Branching / Tagging](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html).  But that sometimes might be confusing since the files' set is the same and you always need to remember in what folder you are doing modifications.

It seems to be that you misuse the concept of trunk/branches/tags. That is, you should use **switch command** to switch between trunk, branches, tags. Check one of the workflows and choose one to follow. Check [this article](http://emilsblog.lerch.org/2010/03/working-with-feature-branch-in.html)